# Not able to read /dev/block/sda after connecting USB in Android 11

Tags: android, android-source, android-11

I am facing an issue while connecting a USB. I cannot access or read the "/dev/block/sda" folder in Android 11.
Even though I added the below permissions, I can still not read( "/dev/block/sda").
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Below is the error I am getting,

"Exception while reading data from file: /dev/block/sda1: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

type=1400 audit(0.0:853): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/block" dev="tmpfs" ino=11
scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
"
So what is the SELinux rule to add in AOSP for reading the above folder? or how can I resolve this issue?

Added app level permission for read/write and app is system app with permissive mode.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`